# SSIS package configuration parent variable not being passed

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am testing two simple packages in a project in SSIS 2008. I have parent package with a variable and I would like pass that variable down to the child package called from parent using an Execute Package Task. I am using Package Configurations choosing the Parent Package Variable option. However, the child package is not picking up the variable. I have checked the config over and over and the variable names are exactly the same (I know it is case sensetive). Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to resolve it by removing the child variable and recreating it and then recreating the package configuration. It looks like I had lost a link to the variable or something.

Answer (score 2):

this is the process I've used and have had great results.

First make sure you're editing the package configuration of your child package, and the variable exists in both your parent and child package.

Then in the package configuration wizard at "Select Configuration Type"  Make sure configuration type is set to "Parent Package Variable" and that the text you enter into "Parent variable:" matches the name of the variable in parent package exactly.  Should look like User::Var1. Hit next

On the "Select Target Property" screen, under your child package, in variables select the variable you want the data to go into, open that variables properties, then select the Value property. This is where the value of the parent variable is going to go.

in this example
child -> Variables -> Var1 -> Properties -> Value
hit next

Give this config a name and hit finish.

hope this helped.